# Select Max in inner join Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, max, inner-join

How do I convert this sql query to Sequelize?

**select a.id, a.name, max(b.sentAt) as sentAt from stations as a inner join monitoring_data_info as b on a.id = b.stationId group by a.id, a.name**

And the result is this: [image]

I try this code but it does not run:

```
static findStationInfo (){
    return this.findAll({
      attributes : ['id', 'name', [Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('sentAt')), 'sentAt']],
      include: [{model: MonitoringDataInfo, attributes : [], required: true}],
      group: ['Station.id', 'Station.name']
    })
  }
```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the attribute: raw: true

```
static findStationInfo (){
    return this.findAll({
      attributes : ['id', 'name', [Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('sentAt')), 'sentAt']],
      include: [{model: MonitoringDataInfo, attributes : [], required: true}],
      group: ['Station.id', 'Station.name'],
      **raw: true**
    })
  }
```